# How would I should I shorten the following piece of code?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have the following piece of code. It is simple and does the job... But it's too lengthy for my liking.

```
if ( isInputValid( userInput ) ) {
    return userInput;
} else {
    console.log('User Input is Invalid!');
}
```

Normally, I would just be able to use a ternary operator. However, in this case, I can't.

```
// not possible, invalid
isInputValid( userInput ) ? return userInput : console.log('User Input is Invalid!');
```

But, is there another way to shorten and further simplify the `if` and `else` statement? Anything like the fat arrow syntax, etc?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Don’t focus on making your code short. Instead, focus on making it easily read by other people. I would leave it as is.

Comment: @DanielRead With all due respect, more often than not, shorter code is proportional to its ease in terms of readability. 

To everybody else who has downvoted this question: This is part of the learning process for me... So, kindly allow me to ask such questions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Eh i would never use a ternary operator for this use case for the simple fact that my next employee that would be working with this code might not have used them extensively and itd slow them down for a few seconds. But to each their own wish you the best of luck on your learning path!

Comment: @DanielRead I am not an advanced javascript developer myself and try to continuously learn daily, but if you think your next employee would have issues with the ternary operator, then... I would suggest him/her join me on my journey to further improve our skills. I am really not trying to be funny here, but... The ternary operator is not exactly "advanced" by any measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a few options. First, since you appear to be returning from a function, you could shorten your initial code by simply omitting the else part.

```
if ( isInputValid( userInput ) ) {
  return userInput;
}
console.log('User Input is Invalid!');
```

Now you could still use a ternary operator if you want, you just need to return the result of the ternary operator itself.

```
return isInputValid(userInput) ? userInput : console.log('User Input is Invalid!');
```

Comment: Thank you for that Nick. To follow up about the ternary operator... Wouldn't that return the value in either case?

Comment: It would only return userInput if it’s valid, otherwise it returns the console log

Comment: Hmmm. I am slightly confused. The return would happen AFTER the ternary operator has finished doing its job, `true` or `false`. In the case of `false`, the console would log the statement, and then the `return` would be executed still.

Comment: Yes, if it’s false then the return value of console.log will be returned, which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Nick's answer, a good way to shorten this code would be to simply do the following.

```
if ( isInputValid( userInput ) ) return userInput;
console.log('User Input is Invalid!');
```

Being able to remove the braces, due to it being a single statement, followed by removing the `else` as `console.log()` will really only be executed if the previous statement is `false` anyway. So, it renders the `else` unnecessary.

Short and simple, beautiful!